# Why is it 'come' and not 'comes' in 'it is important that he come...'?

Tags: subjunctives, mandative

We usually add 's' or 'es' to the first form of the verb when the subject is a third person. I do not understand why 's' hasn't been added to the verb "come" in the following sentence:

> It is important that he **come** to my party.

Comment: It is present tense subjunctive.

Comment: In the USA, you will commonly hear it said and see it written with the "s", even though that's technically incorrect.

Comment: As a native speaker in the US, *not* putting the "s" at the end sounds very, very weird to me. I would always say it as "It is important that he **comes** to my party"

Comment: There's nothing incorrect about it, technically or otherwise.

Comment: Also as a native US speaker, to me it sounds quite formal or "British" without the "s".  I would normally use it with an "s", as mentioned above.

Comment: Instinctive and correct use of the subjunctive is a marker of erudition, in my experience. This may translate as "weird," "formal," "British," "pretentious," or "huh? He said whaaaa?" depending upon the audience in the United States. I intentionally eschew the subjunctive in many situations. For instance, I would never say to a driver in reference to a shipment: "It is necessary that it arrive before 7."

Answer (score 18):

**Short answer**:

Because [subjunctive mood](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subjunctive_mood) obligates the following:

> The present tense third person singular drops the -s or -es so that it looks and sounds like the present tense for everything else. — [source](http://englishplus.com/grammar/00000031.htm).

**Longer answer**:

Well, many argue that the subjunctive mood is disappearing from English. Somewhat rightfully so, considering that other languages tend to have more sophisticated subjunctive systems.

*How does subjunctive "work"?* This is the same reason some people insist that you use

> If I ***were*** able to swim, . . .

rather than

> If I ***was*** able to swim, . . .

For most verbs, the only visible and distinct difference is the one you noticed: No *-s* or *-es* ending as otherwise would've existed. For verb 'be', we both have "be" and "were" subjunctives, which of course, are used in present and past tenses, respectively.

> I urge that she ***meet*** Dr. Whom ASAP.
>
> I think I clearly stated that I disagree with the piece of advice that he ***be*** the guy to confess to uncommitted crimes.
>
> If I ***were*** you, I would've hired a consultant.

For the most part, **indicative mood** is subjunctive mood's counterpart.

*When should I use subjunctive mood in modern English grammar?* John Lawler has [a notable post](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/116698/125563) on when to use subjunctive mood in modern English, and more precisely, the patterns in which the subjunctive appears. To quote the answer:

> There are four patterns, with four different kinds of complement-taking impositive predicates:
>
> > 1) Transitive impositive communication verbs:
> >     *insist, suggest, demand, prefer, propose, suggest, recommend, demand, ask, mandate, prefer, request, ask, desire, advise, urge, specify, instruct, order, demand, insist, require, rule, necessitate, suffice, advocate, vote, would rather,* and *move* (in the parliamentary sense).
> >
> > **Pattern**: `NPVolit` `Verb` ***that*** [`NP` + `Infinitive VP`]
> >
> > 2) Transitive impositive emotive predicate adjective: *adamant*
> >
> > **Pattern**: `NPVolit` be `Adj` ***that*** [`NP` + `Inf VP`]
> >
> > 3) Intransitive impositive predicate adjectives (normally with Extraposition):
> >     *necessary, desirable, imperative, important, necessary, preferable, optional, permissible, acceptable, okay, all right, satisfactory, desirable, advisable, sufficient, necessary, mandatory, urgent, vital, crucial, essential, fitting, right, appropriate, better, expedient,* and *legitimate*
> >
> > **Pattern**: ***That*** [`NP` + `Inf VP`] *be* `Adj` = Extraposition => *It be* `Adj` ***that*** [`NP` + `Inf VP`]
> >
> > 4) Picture nouns derived from impositive predicates:
> >      *recommendation, necessity, insistence, proposal, preference, request, desire, advice, suggestion, option, alternative, recommendation, demand, requirement, necessity, imperative, condition, mandate, specification, rule, ruling, edict, instruction, principle, prerequisite, order, qualification, ultimatum, vote,* and *motion* (in the parliamentary sense).
> >
> > **Pattern**: [`PictureN` ***that*** [`NP` + `Inf VP`]] (not a clause, but an NP with a complement clause)

<sub>Examples omitted to prevent from adding unnecessary length to the answer</sub>

Back to your sentence,

> It is important that he ***come*** to my party.

It uses the subjunctive mood and fits pattern 3.

*And what does it mean?* Various online sources for learning English agree that subjunctive mood refer to a *conditional* or *doubtful* situation. Subjunctive is an [irrealis mood](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irrealis_mood), meaning, it doesn't necessarily point to something real. He may come to the party, he may not. To quote Wikipedia

> Subjunctive forms of verbs are typically used to express various states of unreality such as wish, emotion, possibility, judgment, opinion, obligation, or action that has not yet occurred; the precise situations in which they are used vary from language to language.
>   The English subjunctive is used to form sentences that do not describe known objective facts. These include statements about one's state of mind, such as opinion, belief, purpose, intention, or desire. — [English Subjuctive, Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_subjunctive)

So what the sentence means is "His coming into my party is important." *This course of action (**coming to the party**) he will take may happen or not as it refers to the future, but it's **important** that he does it.*

Comment: Wouldn't it thus be '...but it's important that he do it'?

Comment: @User many modern grammarians would argue that it's completely acceptable -- though incorrect technically -- to use the indicative mood there. You won't get a correction from many native speakers if you say it like that.