# independent clause or not?

Tags: clauses

> Though absolute justice be unattainable, *as much justice as we need for all practical use is attainable by all those who make it their aim.*

why is "*as much justice as we need for all practical use is attainable by all those who make it their aim.*" an independent clause?

As per my knowledge, the clause before the comma is a dependent clause which can not be on its own for a meaningful sentence. it needs an independent clause to which it attaches itself.

source: ["be" or "being"? "And though absolute justice be unattainable, as much justice as we need for all practical use is attainable"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/75532/be-or-being-and-though-absolute-justice-be-unattainable-as-much-justice-a/75534#75534)

Comment: What do you mean by *independent*? Defining or non—defining?

Comment: @Ale An independent clause is one which is not subordinated to ("dependent on") another clause: it can stand alone as a sentence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stripped down to basics, the clause in question has the form

> X          is Y.
>   Justice is attainable.

That is a simple independent clause of the form S-V-PC (Subject-Verb-Predicate Complement).

Everything else in that clause acts as a modifier to one of those three terms.

> *How much justice?* → as much _ as we need
>   *Why do we need it?* → for all practical use
>   *Attainable by whom?* → by those
>   *Which those?*  → who make justice their aim