# If he were Or If he was

Tags: verbs, past-tense, singular-vs-plural

I saw this [New York Times article](http://www.nytimes.com/2016/01/14/opinion/campaign-stops/why-i-will-never-vote-for-donald-trump.html?_r=0):

> Mr. Trump’s presence in the 2016 race has already had pernicious effects, but they’re nothing compared with what would happen if ***he were*** the Republican standard-bearer. The nominee, after all, is the leader of the party; he gives it shape and definition.

According to normal grammar rules, one should write "he is", "he was", "they are", and "they were".  So, in the article above, is "he were" wrong?  Should "he ***were***" be changed to "he ***was***"?

Comment: Actually, according to *strict* grammar rules, ***were*** is correct, and ***was*** is "wrong". But increasing numbers of native speakers don't bother with the subjunctive in such contexts.

Comment: Related: http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/72518/ More and more people are going for the indicative mood, but subjunctive still is far from vanishing.

Answer (score 5):

This is an example of something called the **Subjunctive Mood**—a tricky aspect of verb usage in many languages.  It occurs most often in conditional statements or descriptions of hypothetical situations, but there are enough scenarios where the Subjunctive is correct that I'd just recommend reading [this article](http://grammarist.com/grammar/subjunctive-mood/) to get them all.

The sentence, therefore, is grammatically correct because the described situation *(Trump as Republican standard bearer)* is not currently true.  Compare:

> **Trump was** the Republican standard bearer. *(Factual)*
>
> **If Trump were** the Republican standard bearer... *(Hypothetical)*

The use of the subjunctive is a formal grammatical rule with very specific applications that are sometimes difficult to identify properly.  It is very common even for native speakers to ignore it in everyday speech, saying things like **If I was** rather than the formally correct **If I were**.  Formal writing, however, requires it for proper usage.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong.

In conditional structures, *was* for the first and third person is often changed with *were*. For instance: *I wouldn't do that if I **were** you.*