# Which of the two is correct? Which to use: was or were?

Tags: grammar, tense

(A) He talks about his wife as if she WERE an angel descended from heaven.
(B) He talks about his wife as if she WAS an angel descended from heaven.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [If he were Or If he was.](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/83009/if-he-were-or-if-he-was) Also [Why is it "If I were you" and not "If I was you"?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/23853/why-is-it-if-i-were-you-and-not-if-i-was-you) and ***many*** more.

Answer (score 0):

> (A) He talks about his wife as if she WERE an angel descended from heaven.

Formal style.

> (B) He talks about his wife as if she WAS an angel descended from heaven.

Informal style.

Both are possible.

Comment: That doesn't make things any clearer! I am still as clueless as before.

Comment: @IftikharShafia It's an "unreal" comparison, things we know that are not true.  It's the same as:  He talks as if he WAS rich. (But he is definitely not). In a formal style, WERE can be used instead of WAS: He talks as if he WERE rich.

Comment: Things are gradually becoming clearer, I concede.

Answer (score 0):

In formal English, when using the verb 'be' in an if clause for an **unreal** conditional sentence, we conjugate it as **were**, no matter what the subject is. This is true even if the subject is first-person singular (I) or third-person singular (he, she, or it).

In your example sentence, the man's wife is not an angel descended from heaven.

*If I were a rich man, I’d buy a baseball team (I am not a rich man).

If I were the king, I'd sell all my palaces (I am not the king).*

However, in informal spoken English, many people ignore this and use **was** instead, possibly because they think it 'sounds better'.

Comment: I say you have cracked my problem in one. If you want to prove your erudition, use were; otherwise, if you are just a pedestrian, use was. I think I have got the gist of it. Thank you.

Comment: @IftikharShafia - your comment about 'proving erudition' is misplaced.

Comment: "Erudition", in this context, means strict adherence to grammar and its rules, or at least that is what I was thinking of. Of course, if my comment is grossly out of place then I have no hesitation in withdrawing it.

Comment: @IftikharShafia - OK. I thought you meant 'boasting about one's learning' which is an unwelcome suggestion, and inaccurate as a general observation.

Comment: No, Sir, absolutely not! I wasn't being rude to you. I have my shortcomings, but heaven forbid I should be so ill-bred as to say such a thing to one who is trying to help me with my English.

Comment: @IftikharShafia - I am sure you meant no offence, but the fact is that some native speakers consider formal language to be affected and boastful. I am not one of those.